# pass parameters from Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel to calling method

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

need help on this
From the below code I want to pass some parameters to calling function which is genericInnerCopy
But I can't pass parameters, bydefault model as parameter is passed

```
                var that = child;
                that._type = 'PortfolioItem/' + that.get('PortfolioItemTypeName');
                Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModel({
                    type: that._type,
                    success: this.genericInnerCopy,
                    scope: this
                });
```

In the below method I want to use the child object from the above method

```
                genericInnerCopy: function(model) {
                this.model = model;
                var record = Ext.create(this.model, {
                    Name: child.get('Name'),
                });
                record.save;
                },
```

Any suggestions on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `this` points to the app,

```
var that = this;
```

You may create an object that is available anywhere in the app:

```
that._child = child;
```

and you don't have to pass a reference to it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks nick. But the child object has to change everytime.  I am looping through the Features, MMFs.